# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in VBA in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get the following error message: 3075 missing operator in query expression

here a short snippet of the code:

```
Dim dbs As Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
dbs.Execute "DELETE FROM TempTable_Entity_mapping_DEFSET_Selection;"
Do While Not rsDEFSET.EOF
    Debug.Print rsDEFSET.Fields.item("RESULT").Value
    MIP = rsDEFSET.Fields.item("FK_DIM_MBR_ITEM").Value
    KPIName = rsDEFSET.Fields.item("SHORTNAME_MBR").Value
    ID = rsDEFSET.Fields.item("RESULT").Value
    DefSetName = rsDEFSET.Fields.item("KPI_DEFSET_NAME")
    Scenarios = rsDEFSET.Fields.item("SCENARIOS")

    fillTempTab = "INSERT INTO TempTable_Entity_mapping_DEFSET_Selection (MIP, KPIName, ID, DefSetName, Scenarios) VALUES ('" & MIP & "','" & KPIName & "','" & ID & "','" & DefSetName & "','" & Scenarios & "');"
    Debug.Print fillTempTab
    dbs.Execute fillTempTab
    rsDEFSET.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Where is `rsDEFSET` defined?

Comment: You should be using prepared statements; especially if you are getting input from an untrusted source. Here's an example of how to use them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572448/msaccess-prepared-statements

Comment: I agree with @bernie, you can store your insert and delete statements in persistent querydefs, then add parameters to the querydef object.  Also, you don't need the '.Fields.item,' rsDefset("field") is fine.

Comment: you get the error on the dbs.execute statement?  also, the ID field is text and not numeric?

Comment: I also wonder if KPIName (or any of the fields) contains a single quote or comma.  what is the value of fillTempTab?

Comment: Unfortunately that last edit change the code to something that will not compile and disguised any real errors. I have rolled back.

Comment: Instead of doing this all through VBA, couldn't you just create an `INSERT INTO` query and post your results directly into `TempTable_Entity_mapping_DEFSET_Selection`? Also would like to echo Ken's comment: where is `rsDEFSET` defined/assigned? Is this from an external db?

Comment: rsDefset is defined a couple of lines above as

`Set rsDEFSET = objCmd.Execute` 
and
`Dim rsDEFSET As New ADODB.Recordset`

Comment: yes, error is on dbs.execute

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing what you want to delete in your SQL statement

Your first query should read

```
DELETE * FROM TempTable_Entity_mapping_DEFSET_Selection;
```