# Join expression not supported - VBA error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following VBA script:

```
Private Sub CmbTermLookup_AfterUpdate()
Dim BusinessTerm As Integer
Dim SqlString As String
If IsNull(Me!CmbTermLookup) Then
  Me!CmbTermLookup = ""
      Else
    BusinessTerm = Me!CmbTermLookup
End If
SqlString = "SELECT TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID,       TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, TblField.FieldID, TblField.FieldName," _
          & " TblField.FieldDescr, TblField.TableID" _
          & " FROM TblBusinessTerm INNER JOIN TblField ON    TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = " & BusinessTerm

Me.RecordSource = SqlString
End Sub
```

I get the error - JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED.

When I run the sqlstring in a query though it works. 
Any ideas why?

Thank you

Comment: Strange...it looks like it should work.  Did you print the exact query string from your VBA code and then try to run that?  Also, consider using prepared statements.  This would eliminate a lot of uncertainty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572448/ms-access-prepared-statements

Comment: How does the query know which records in `TblField` should be joined to each record in `TblBusinessTerm` if the join expression is something like `... ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = 10`?

Comment: I use the variable from the CmbTermLookup which is on a form which I move to the variable BUSINESSTERM in order to pass the ID.
There is no where clause. when I run the query in query design it works, so didnt think that it needed a where clause

Comment: Can you post the string you used in a query that works?  I'm really surprised that you can join two tables without specifying the relationship between the tables.  (But I am more used to just using normal SQL statements - maybe MS Access queries do some sort of guess as to what fields in the two tables are used to join them.)

Comment: SELECT TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID,     TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, TblField.FieldID, TblField.FieldName,   TblField.FieldDescr, TblField.TableID
    
FROM TblBusinessTerm INNER JOIN TblField ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.BusinessTermID;

So all I am trying to do differently here is replace the = TblField.BusinessTermID with a variable

Comment: maybe you should be joining on `INNER JOIN TblField.FieldID ON`

Comment: `ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.BusinessTermID` is **very** different to `ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = 10` - the method that works tells it which fields to join on (the field `BusinessTermID` in `TblBusinessTerm` needs to be equal to the field `BusinessTermID` in `TblField` for a join to occur) while the method that doesn't work gives no information about which field in `TblField` to use.

Comment: Can I not replace the =         Tblfield.businesstermID with a variable ?

Comment: No - it needs to know which **fields** to join the tables on.  Otherwise it doesn't know whether to join the tables by matching the two `BusinessTermID` fields, or perhaps whether to join using `TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.TableID` for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a field in each of the two tables to join the tables on, and then you need to specify a `WHERE` clause if you only want certain records:

```
SqlString = "SELECT TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID, TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, TblField.FieldID, TblField.FieldName," _
          & " TblField.FieldDescr, TblField.TableID" _
          & " FROM TblBusinessTerm INNER JOIN TblField ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.BusinessTermID " _
          & " WHERE TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = " & BusinessTerm
```

Comment: Can I ask please to look then at this SQL string, where LIKE has been used:


    SqlString = "SELECT TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID,    TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, TblField.FieldID, TblField.FieldName," _
              & " TblField.FieldDescr, TblField.TableID" _
              & " FROM TblBusinessTerm INNER JOIN TblField ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.BusinessTermID " _
              & " WHERE TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID like '*" & Me!CmdTitleSimilar & "*'"


It doesnt return a record set at all

Comment: `If IsNull(Me!CmdTitleSimilar) Then
    Me!CmdTitleSimilar = ""
Else
    BusinessTerm = Me!CmdTitleSimilar

End If
SqlString = "SELECT TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID, TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, TblField.FieldID, TblField.FieldName," _
          & " TblField.FieldDescr, TblField.TableID" _
          & " FROM TblBusinessTerm INNER JOIN TblField ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.BusinessTermID " _
          & " WHERE TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID like '*" & Me!CmdTitleSimilar & "*'"'
`

Comment: Yes - spot on - thank you - changed the business term ID to Business term, and issue resolved. 

Thank you for all your help

Comment: @Jext It's probably a good idea to delete all the "off-topic" comments we have just been posting - they're nothing to do with the actual question