# How to INNER JOIN 4 tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I had to create an addressbook application connecting a database to a java gui. I'm working on my search button right now and almost got it but cant figure out how to connect all four tables. I need to search by a last name and then I want it to show all related information from that person.

[image]

So far this is what I have and it seems to be working but when I try to INNER JOIN emailAddresses and phoneNumbers I get a syntax error.

```
resultSet =
    statement.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM names INNER JOIN addresses ON names.personID = addresses.personID WHERE lastName LIKE '%" + last + "%' ");
            resultSet.next();
            jTextField1.setText(resultSet.getString("firstName"));
            jTextField2.setText(resultSet.getString("lastName"));
            jTextField3.setText(resultSet.getString("address1"));
            jTextField4.setText(resultSet.getString("address2"));
            jTextField5.setText(resultSet.getString("city"));
            jTextField6.setText(resultSet.getString("state"));
            jTextField7.setText(resultSet.getString("zipcode"));
            jTextField8.setText(resultSet.getString("phoneNumber"));
            jTextField9.setText(resultSet.getString("emailAddress"));
```

Comment: You should edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.  I doubt that a `JOIN` is what you really want.

Comment: If  just join multiple tables is your requirement then there exists lots of tutorials in google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to add brackets and use `*` rather than `%` as the wildcard.
I haven't tested, but this should work:

```
"SELECT     *
FROM    ((names INNER JOIN addresses ON names.personID = addresses.personID)
                INNER JOIN emailadresses ON names.personID = emailadresses.PersonID)
                INNER JOIN PhoneNumbers ON names.PersonID = PhoneNumbers.PersonID
WHERE   lastName LIKE '*" & last & "*'"
```

Saying it should work - remember to escape the apostrophe in any last name.
 [Escaping ' in Access SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199889/escaping-in-access-sql)

Comment: Thanks! I feel like I'm almost there its just now I'm getting an INVALID CURSOR STATE error

Comment: I wasn't able to add the '&' I would get compiler error as bad operand type

Comment: That must be the Java - sorry, should have said I wrote it as a VBA text string.  I guess in Java you use the `+` (you can in VBA but may end up with the two parts being summed rather than concatenated).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM names A
INNER JOIN address B ON A.personID = B.personID
INNER JOIN emailAddress C ON A.personID = C.personID
INNER JOIN phoneNumbers D ON A.personID = D.personID
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

try this SQL Command, joining four tables is the same as joining one table or joining many more tables:

`SELECT firstName, lastName, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, phoneNumber, emailAddress 
FROM names 
INNER JOIN addresses 
ON names.personID = addresses.personID 
INNER JOIN emailadresses
ON names.personID = emailadresses.PersonID
INNER JOIN PhoneNumbers
ON names.PersonID = PhoneNumbers.PersonID
WHERE lastName LIKE '%parameter%'`

Comment: I tried this but for some reason I keep getting a syntax error. its driving me crazy I don't know why its doing that. It just says ACCESS DATABSE (missing operator) syntax error - and lists my select statement-  I have re checked it 5 times and everything looks fine

Comment: do you have a variable that is limited in number of characters? for example NVARCHAR(200) that need to be set to a larger value NVARCHAR(4000)? just guessing!